# Convert from MM/DD/YYYY to DD-MM-YYY

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data in csv file which has some entries in the MM/DD/YYYY format and some entries in the DD-MM-YYYY format. I would like to read this column of entries and store it as a new column in a pandas dataframe? How would I go about this?

Example:

```
    Entry        Sampling Date
     1            01-10-2004
     2            01-13-2004
     3            16/1/2004
```

I would like to convert the first two rows' date format to that in the third row.

Comment: `.replace("/","-")`?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: and swap the month and day..

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, i missed that

Comment: please check duplicated answer, maybe need only change `format='%d/%m/%Y'` to `format='%m/%d/%Y'`. If there is problem, let me know, I can remove duplicates box

Comment: @jezrael I am getting some entries as NaT. The problem seems to be that the year is not mentioned in full. 3rd Jan, 2004 is 03-01-04.

Comment: I realize that is not what I showed in the example. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `datetime` module, define a function and then apply it to your column

```
import datetime.datetime 

def read_date(string):
    if '/' in entry:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(string,'%m/%d/%Y')
    elif '-' in entry:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, '%d-%m-%Y')
    return date

# If df is your dataframe
df['newdate'] = df['Sampling Date'].apply(read_date)
```

Comment: I think this will work. However, as I mentioned in the comment above, the year is not mentioned in full, 3rd January, 2004 is written as 03-01-04. This gives me errors.

Comment: That is not what you showed in your example... then simply replace %Y by %y and that will do the trick. Obviously if you have some lines with truncated year and other with year in full, you will have to make an if clause to choose which way to parse

Comment: Yes, I realize that's not what I showed in the example. My bad. Thanks for the answer. It works now